# Does Ef Code First support batch CUD, and do you have examples?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I have tried to google this question without finding any answers.
I am trying to batch update/insert entities in a wcf, entity frame work project.
My question is does Entity Framework 4.1(code first) support batch insert, update and delete?
And if ef 4.1 does support cud, do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework (all versions) supports CUD (insert, update, delete) but it doesn't support batching commands. It means that each insert, update and delete are executed in separate roundtrip to the database.

This has no relation to WCF. If you want batching over WCF you just need to send collection of objects for processing and let them process on the server by EF (without batching). WCF data services supports batching for passing multiple objects to server within one roundtrip.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, clearing things up. Then it is of to nhibernate again:)